# Unreadable Notebook,Notebook does not appear to be JSON:

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just purchased a new laptop and transfered my ipnyb files on it.
I installed python and anaconda and ran Jupyter Notebook, I tried to run those files but unfortunately I have the same error message : "Unreadable Notebook, Notebook does not appear to be JSON".

I seeked for answers on Internet and looked into the .ipnyb_checkpoints directory but unfortunatly there's nothing inside. I checked on my previous laptop and realised that this directory contains all my files. I don't know when I put the wrong settings during the installation of anaconda, inducing an empty directory file.

Please, does someone have a solution for this problem ?

Comment: The paragraph about seeing answers on the internet doesn't make sense if you are looking to solve the error message. We need to know more about the files you do have? It sounds like you were using older Jupyter on your old machine. Chances are good though **if you have the actual notebook files with code** that they can be converted to work with the new Jupyter on your new system. Can you open a very simple short one of your notebooks in a text editor and then copy that code to a snippet sharing service like pastebin or [gist](https://gist.gisthub.com) and then share the URL here?

Comment: I'm kind of hoping your issue is similar to this [one where someone seemed to have older style notebook files](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/invalid-notebook-the-notebook-does-not-appear-to-be-valid-json-on-github/12604/4?u=fomightez). Start with just trying to understand what is being said in the first three paragraphs, above the double lines, if you want to investigate yours on your own further. However, your issue may be completely different, but still clicking the link there in front of `,which is nice json` should give you an idea of what hopefully you'll end up with at some point soon.

Comment: Correct link to gist is `https://gist.github.com/`. That one doesn't allow anonymous code sharing as you need an account. There's others that allow you not to have an account. I thought pastebin did. I'm not suggesting you paste your code here because it may be huge and you being new to Stackoverflow, you may not know how to paste code as part of a post to keep the formatting and it will cause more confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Wayne.These are jupyer notebook files. You are right the two versions aren't the same,I updated jupyter notebook on my old laptop but doesnt seem to work either.I tried to download some ipnyb files from internet on both machines and seemed to work correctly, i can also create a new jupyter notebook and works aswell.My issue is transfering those files I guess. Tried to post on github but didnt work (same error message) and tried to convert to html then pdf and back to ipnyb. This time i could open the file but the format wasnt the good one.here is some code you asked for:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/L-Illustre-Jacques-Hadamard/128de1915fd4f3ef7429832e3c96b393#file-gistfile1-txt. 
Is the file you are talking to ?

Comment: my issue has to be similar as the one you linked 
https://gist.github.com/L-Illustre-Jacques-Hadamard/2486b41463fb4f4baf6399f7819a82f4

Comment: Yes, neither file that you provide in your last two comments are jupyter notebooks in current json format of modern notebooks. The one ending in `.txt` looks to be code from cells in the notebook. And the other is the HTML version of the notebook. Getting the code in the text file back into a modern notebook, should be straightforward. How graceful it is different question. Do you have a lot of that type to convert and need help? I didn't study the example you provided enough to tell if separate cells are indicated anyway.

Comment: Similarly, with the HTML files. Do you have a mix of those in text and in HTML format? How many HTML ones? The HTML you provided looks to be a complex one involving widgets. Any simpler ones that are only in HTML form that we could start with? The great news is it seems your underlying code is still all there. You may need to consider what is important in the long run to convert to modern notebooks and prioritize for now? It's hard to advise yet not knowing what you absolutely need vs. number.

Comment: thank you @Wayne for your help i've found how to transfer my notebooks, the only issue is that i have to do it one by one and i have 50 but it might be OK

Comment: Yes, I was hoping it was only a few. Chances are there's a much better way to do it. Or at least do the bulk of the work to bring it into a proper notebook file. Is one of the two you've shared above a typical one you've converted? If so, pointing out how you took that specific file and at least did the processing for the top part of it or up to where it became repetitious? Feel feel to link to an easier example file. I suspect with some of the tools in the Jupyter toolchain you could get farther towards having all 50 back to notebooks sooner. Maybe not entirely perfected, but useable.